# Combine to table without joins

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two these two tables

TableA

```
       Col1 Col2
        1     A
        5     B
        3     A
```

TableB

```
 Column1 Column2
    11     Aa
    15     Bb
```

How can i get this resultset, while ordering by TableA.col1 desc and TableB.Column1 desc

```
       Col1 Col2 Column1 Column2
        1     A    11     Aa
        3     B    15     Bb
        5     A
```

Tried this `SELECT * FROM (SELECT*, 1 sortby    FROM TableA ) a,(SELECT *, 2 sortby FROM TableB ) b ORDER BY a.sortby`

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the logic for making `1, A, 11, Aa` one row and not `5, A, 11, Aa` ?

Comment: Well we have ordered TableA  using Col1 desc and TableB using Column1 desc so logically it will be `1 A 11`

Comment: You can't have `3 B` when in your tableA have data as `3 A`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this... (did not test it)

```
SELECT
  a.col1,
  a.col2,
  b.column1,
  b.column2
FROM 
(
      SELECT
        col1,
        col2,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col1 DESC) AS rownum
      FROM tableA
) AS a
FULL OUTER JOIN 
(
      SELECT
        column1,
        column2,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY column1 DESC) AS rownum
      FROM tableB
) AS b
ON a.rownum = b.rownum
```

Comment: You might go with `FULL JOIN` since you don't know which table will have more rows.